# Hybris: How to create a promotion "Order threshold change delivery mode(free delivery) "

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

> 1.I want to overriding  default promotion in hybris.
>
> 2.Which one we need  to overriding "if our order amount more then X then we give free delivery".

Comment: What have you tried? Which version of hybris are you using? Promotions system have changed.

Comment: i want to implement free delivery promotion based on order amount in  hybris 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hybris 6 you can use the template `y_change_delivery_mode`.

You can either configure it from the backoffice - see the [documentation](https://help.hybris.com/6.1.0/hcd/5751c7a78d574c39902056ce7dc12188.html).

Or you can import it in Impex (Syntax is quite ugly - use a json formatter to read it) :

```
;order_threshold_change_delivery_mode;70;1;false;orderPromotionRuleGroup;"[{""children"":[],""parameters"":{""value"":{""type"":""Map(ItemType(Currency),java.math.BigDecimal)"",""uuid"":""b07060b4-bcb0-4016-b778-e3c566051df4"",""value"":{""USD"":100}},""operator"":{""type"":""Enum(de.hybris.platform.ruledefinitions.AmountOperator)"",""uuid"":""c3217773-9e3b-4b22-8251-c4626251d854"",""value"":""GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL""}},""definitionId"":""y_cart_total""}]";"[{""parameters"":{""delivery_mode"":{""value"":""free-standard-shipping""}},""definitionId"":""y_change_delivery_mode""}]";
```

You'll have to replace in the impex `{""USD"":100}` with the desired cart threshold. You also have to create a delivery mode with free delivery cost. This delivery mode is referred as `free-standard-shipping` in the impex.

Comment: In apparel it is not working but electronics it is working.

Comment: @FajruddinSk Yes if you keep "100$" you have to make sure that your basket is in dollar. In electronics there is only USD and JPY. You probably have a cart in dollar. In apparel you have several currencies, maybe your cart is in EUR or GBP.